# Angular material two way binding on select returning undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material

For some reason category is returning undefined.

component

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" class="login-form d-flex flex-column m-auto">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
      <mat-select placeholder="Product type" formControlName="category" (valueChange)="search()" >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let cate of this.categories" [value]="cate">{{ cate }}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

And the components TypeScript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Products } from "../../Products";
import { ProductService } from "../../services/product.service";
import {ShoppingCartService} from "../../services/shopping-cart.service";
import {BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints} from "@angular/cdk/layout";
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent {

  searchForm: FormGroup;

  category: string;
  categories: string[] = ['CPU', 'GPU', 'HDD'];
  searchForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() {}

  search(): void {
    console.log(this.category); // undefined

  }

}
```

I tried binding it many other ways but no more what I do it always returning undefined

Comment: If you want to use 2-way binding then it should be `[(value)]` and not `[value]`. And since you are using angular forms, you would need to use `[(ngModel)]` on the select element

Comment: I think you should add 'category' as FormControl to your FornGroup.

Comment: You are mixing template driven and reactive form. Use either one. In your template you have defined as reactive form however in component its template driven form.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a few things, let's go step by step.
As You are using Reactive Forms, I'll recommend not to use 2-way binding directly i.e. `[(ngModel)]`, rather use the functionality that Reactive Forms provides.

You created the `searchFrom: FromGroup`, but it's not initialized, so first we have to initialize it, I'll use Angular's `FormBuilder Service` to achieve that, we'll also need to add the `formControl` in the `searchForm` that You are using in Your HTML form group

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {} 

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
        category: [{ value: '', disabled: false }],
    });
}
```

Now there are two ways you can get the category from `mat-select`. Either you can utilize the `FormControl.valueChanges` method or you can use `(selectionChange)` method of `mat-select`

**The first method will look like this (Recommended):**

First we create a method that subscribes to the `valueChanges` property.

```
subscribeToCategoryValueChanges(): void {
    this.searchForm.controls.category.valueChanges.subscribe(resp => {
        console.log(resp);
    }); 
}
```

Then we'll simply call that function in our `ngOnInit()`

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
         category: [{ value: '', disabled: false }],
      });

      this.subscribeToCategoryValueChanges();
}
```

Also, we'll have to remove the `search()` function from our HTML as it is no longer required

```
    <form [formGroup]="searchForm" class="login-form d-flex flex-column m-auto">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
              <mat-select placeholder="Product type" formControlName="category">
                 <mat-option *ngFor="let cate of categories" [value]="cate">{{ 
                 cate }}</mat-option>
               </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```

**The second method will look like this:**

```
    search(): void {
       console.log(this.searchForm.controls.category.value);
    }
```

You'll also have to update your HTML and replace `(valueChange)` with `(selectionChange)`

```
    <form [formGroup]="searchForm" class="login-form d-flex flex-column m-auto">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
              <mat-select placeholder="Product type" formControlName="category" 
              (selectionChange)="search()" >
                 <mat-option *ngFor="let cate of categories" [value]="cate">{{ 
                 cate }}</mat-option>
               </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```